# A better way to extract functions from an R script?

Tags: r, bash, function, split

Say I have a file "myfuncs.R" with a few functions in it:

```
A <- function(x) x
B <- function(y) y
C <- function(z) z
```

I want to place all the functions contained within "myfuncs.R" into their own files, named appropriately.  I have a simple Bash-shell script to extract functions and place them in separate files:

```
split -p "function\(" myfuncs.R tmpfunc
grep "function(" tmpfunc* | awk '{
  # strip first-instances of function assignment
  sub("<-", " ")
  sub("=", " ")
  sub(":", " ")  # and colon introduced by grep
  mv=$1
  mvto=sprintf("func_%s.R",$2)
  print "mv", mv, mvto
}' | sh
```

leaving me with:

```
func_A.R
func_B.R
func_C.R
```

But, this script has obvious limitations.  For example, it will misbehave when function 'A' has a nested function:

```
A <- function(x){
    Aa <- function(x){x}
    return(Aa)
}
```

and outright fails if the whole function is on a single line.

Does anyone know of a more robust, and less error-prone method to do this?

Comment: That's the goal, but creating documentation seems much easier if the functions are split into individual files.

Comment: Not true. Use `roxygen` to create inline documentation.

Comment: @Andrie, I prefer `roxygen2` ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Source your functions and then type `package.skeleton()`

Separate files will be made for each function.

Comment: Note that `dump` is the function used in `package.skeleton()` to write the text representations of 'function' objects.  So, if you just wanted to save the functions and not deal with the package framework, you could use that.