# R: How to check if the libraries that I am loading, I use them for my code in R?

Tags: r, package, libraries

I have used several packages of R libraries for my study. All libraries charge together at the beginning of my code. And here is the problem. It turns out that I have done several tests with different functions that were already in the packages of R. However, in the final code I have not implemented all the functions I have tried. Therefore, I am loading libraries that I do not use.

**Would there be any way to check the libraries to know if they really are necessary for my code?**

Comment: you can use `packrat` in your projects to be in control of packages that you use

Comment: Delete them all (by commenting out the `library` or `require` calls), and then fix errors by adding them back as necessary.

Comment: See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NCmisc/versions/1.1.5/topics/list.functions.in.file and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755555/1989480

Answer (score 4):

Start by restarting R with a fresh environment, no libraries loaded. For this demonstration, I'm going to define two functions:

```
zoo1 <- function() na.locf(1:10)
zoo2 <- function() zoo::na.locf(1:10)
```

With no libraries loaded, let's try something:

```
codetools::checkUsage(zoo1)
# <anonymous>: no visible global function definition for 'na.locf'
codetools::checkUsage(zoo2)
library(zoo)
# Attaching package: 'zoo'
# The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
codetools::checkUsage(zoo1)
```

Okay, so we know we can check a single function to see if it is abusing scope and/or using non-base functions. Let's assume that you've loaded your script full of functions (but not the calls to `require` or `library`), so let's do this process for all of them. Let's first unload `zoo`, so that we'll see a complaint again about our `zoo1` function:

```
detach("package:zoo", unload=TRUE)
```

Now let's iterate over all functions:

```
allfuncs <- Filter(function(a) is.function(get(a)), ls())
str(sapply(allfuncs, function(fn) capture.output(codetools::checkUsage(get(fn))), simplify=FALSE))
# List of 2
#  $ zoo1: chr "<anonymous>: no visible global function definition for 'na.locf'"
#  $ zoo2: chr(0)
```

Now you know to look in the function named `zoo1` for a call to `na.locf`. It'll be up to you to find in which not-yet-loaded package this function resides, but that might be more more reasonable, depending on the number of packages you are loading.

Some side-thoughts:

1. If you have a script file that does not have everything comfortably ensconced in functions, then just wrap all of the global R code into a single function, say `bigfunctionfortest <- function() {` as the first line and `}` as the last. Then source the file and run `codetools::checkUsage(bigfunctionfortest)`.
2. Package developers have to go through a process that uses this, so that the `Imports:` and `Depends:` sections of [`NAMESPACE`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces) (another ref: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) will be correct. One good trick to do that will prevent "namespace pollution" is loading the namespace but not the package ... and though that may sound confusing, it often results in using `zoo::na.locf` for all non-base functions. This gets old quickly (especially if you are using `dplyr` and such, where most of your daily functions are non-base), suggesting those oft-used functions should be directly imported instead of just referenced wholly. If you're familiar with python, then:

   ```
   # R
   library(zoo)
   na.locf(c(1,2,NA,3))
   ```

   is analagous to

   ```
   # fake-python
   from zoo import *
   na_locf([1,2,None,3])
   ```

   (if that package/function exists). Then the non-polluting variant looks like:

   ```
   # R
   zoo::na.locf(c(1,2,NA,3))
   # fake-python
   import zoo
   zoo.na_locf([1,2,None,3])
   ```

   where the function's package (and/or subdir packaging) must be used explicitly. There is no ambiguity. It is explicit. This is by some/many considered "A Good Thing (tm)".

   (Language-philes will likely say that `library(zoo)` and `from zoo import *` are not exactly the same ... a better way to describe what is happening is that they bring *everything* from `zoo` into the search path of functions, potentially causing masking as we saw in a console message earlier; while the `::` functionality only loads the namespace but does not add it to the search path. Lots of things going on in the background.)

Comment: In hindsight ... I'm a little surprised and happy I was consistent in using `codetools::checkUsage(...)` vice `library(codetools); checkUsage(...)`, if only for the demonstration of namespace management.

Comment: David, does this answer your question, or are there still unresolved problems?